# Dynamic children / Map type in Relay.js

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relayjs

I have an `Item` Type. I want its title to be translated into a variable number of languages. I was imagining a structure like this:

```
Item {
  title {
    de
    fr
    pa
  }
}
```

The admin interface needs to load all of the titles for editing, and optionally add new ones. In other words, I am looking for a ‘dict’.

The only way I can come up with to solve this right now is to use a `GraphQLString` and encode the language-strings as a JSON objects.

Is there another one, or should there be?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a type to represent a localized string:

```js
const LocalizedStringType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'LocalizedString',
  description: 'A value object that represents a string and a language code',
  fields: () => ({
    languageCode: {type: GraphQLString},
    value: {type: GraphQLString},
  }),
});
```

Then expose a list of objects of this type:

```js
const ItemType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Item',
  fields: () => ({
    localizedTitles: {type: GraphQLList(LocalizedStringType)}
  }),
});
```

In your container, you could operate on this list however you like:

```js
class Item extends React.Component {
  state = {language: 'en'};
  render() {
    const title = (
      this.props.item.localizedTitles.find(localizedString =>
        localizedString.languageCode === this.state.language
      ) ||
      `**Title missing for language with code ${this.state.language}**`
    );
    return <h1>{title}</h1>;
  }
}
Item = Relay.createContainer(Item, {
  fragments: {
    item: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on Item {
        localizedTitles {
          languageCode
          value
        }
      }
    `,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for GraphQLEnumType.

[https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/master/src/**tests**/starWarsSchema.js#L77](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/master/src/__tests__/starWarsSchema.js#L77)

and used as an argument. Like so:
[https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/master/src/**tests**/starWarsSchema.js#L236](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/master/src/__tests__/starWarsSchema.js#L236)

Comment: I don't see how the Enum helps me. I could make the query a call, but I want to load multiple languages at the same time ``title(fr)`` and title(``de``) - is that possible? - but more importantly, I'd like to load all of them without knowing the keys.

Comment: In that case, you'd create a TitleObjectType with those fields.

`type Title{de:String, pa: String, fr: String}`
`type Item{title: Title}`

Comment: Then I would have to define all possible locales in this type - what I wanted to avoid.